# Undergraduate math competition problem: find $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \int \limits^{2006}_{1385}f(nx)\, \mathrm dx$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f\colon [0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and $\displaystyle \lim \limits_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = 1$. Find the following limit:

$$\large\displaystyle \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \int \limits^{2006}_{1385}f(nx)\, \mathrm dx$$

Comment: And what would your guess be?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253696/can-a-limit-of-an-integral-be-moved-inside-the-integral) seems relevant.

Comment: AoPS: [lim integral f(nx) 1385->2006](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h535743_lim_integral_fnx_1385gt2006)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $n\in \Bbb N$ and define $\displaystyle I_n:=\int \limits _{1385}^{2006}f(nx)\,\mathrm dx-621$.

It holds that  $\displaystyle I_n =\int \limits _{1385}^{2006}f(nx)-1 \,\mathrm dx$, therefore $\displaystyle |I_n|\leq \int \limits _{1385}^{2006} \left \vert f(nx)-1\right \vert \,\mathrm dx$.

Recall $\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=1 \iff (\forall \delta >0)(\exists \varepsilon >0)(\forall \overline x\in \Bbb R)(\overline x>\varepsilon \implies |f(\overline x)-1|<\delta)$.

Take $\delta >0$. There exists $\varepsilon >0$ such that for all $\overline x>\varepsilon$ it holds that $|f(\overline x)-1|<\delta$. In particular, for large enough $n$, if $x\ge 1385$, then $|f(nx)-1|<\delta$.

It follows that $\displaystyle |I_n|\leq \int \limits _{1385}^{2006}\delta \,\mathrm dx=621\delta$ and $\lim \limits _{n\to +\infty}\left( |I_n|\right)\leq \lim \limits _{n\to +\infty}\left(621\delta\right)=621\delta$.

Since $\delta$ was an arbitrary positive real number, it was proved that $\lim \limits _{n\to +\infty}\left( |I_n|\right)$ is a lower bound of $\{621\delta \colon\delta >0\}$, therefore $\lim \limits _{n\to +\infty}\left( |I_n|\right)\leq \inf \left(\{621\delta \colon \delta >0\} \right)=0$.

Finally $$\displaystyle 0=\lim \limits _{n\to +\infty}\left( |I_n|\right)=\lim \limits _{n\to +\infty}\left( I_n\right)=\lim \limits _{n\to +\infty}\left( \int \limits _{1385}^{2006}f(nx)\,\mathrm dx-621\right),$$ thus $\displaystyle \int \limits _{1385}^{2006}f(nx)\,\mathrm dx =621.$

Comment: I just realized my change of variable is a bit silly (originally was intended to try to show the integral diverged, which clearly isn't true). I suppose I will adjust it.

Comment: @Evan It's all the same. I got mad when I finished my answer and saw you had already done pretty much the same thing. ^_^

Comment: All good :)  Yours has a lot more detail, so it contributes.

Answer (score 8):

Given $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $M$ for which $|f(x) - 1| \leq \epsilon$ for $x > M$.
Then you can show that

$\left| \int_{1385}^{2006} f(nx) dx - (2006-1385)\right| \leq (2006-1385)\epsilon$

for sufficiently large $n$ (when plugging the left bound of the integrand, $1385n > M$). Finally take $\epsilon \to 0$.

Answer (score 5):

Using the substitution $t=nx$, we get $I_n =  \int^{2006}_{1385}f(nx)dx =  \frac{1}{n}\int_{1385n}^{2006n} f(t) dt$. Let $I=2006-1385$.

Now let $\epsilon>0$, and choose $L>0$ such that if $t\ge L$, then $-\frac{\epsilon}{I} < f(t)-1 < \frac{\epsilon}{I}$.

Now choose $N\ge \frac{L}{1385}$. Then if $n \ge N$ and $t \in [1385n,2006n]$, we have $-\frac{\epsilon}{I} < f(t)-1 < \frac{\epsilon}{I}$. Integrating over $[1385n,2006n]$ and dividing by $n$ gives
$$ -\epsilon  < I_n -I < \epsilon $$
It follows that $\lim_n I_n = I$.

Answer (score 5):

From continuity there is a $\xi_ n \in (1385,2006)$ such that $\int _{1385}^{2006}f(n x) \mathrm{d}x = (2006-1385)f(n \xi _n)$ . 
Since $k_n= n \xi _n \to \infty$ we have
\begin{align}\lim _{n\to \infty}\int _{1385}^{2006}f(n x) \mathrm{d}x &=\lim _{n \to \infty} (2006-1385)f(n \xi _n)\\
&=(2006-1385)\lim _{n \to \infty} f(k_n)=(2006-1385)\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** The Integral Operator is continuous, so you can swap limit and integral. If you have $f \searrow 1$ (monotonously).

Comment: Is continuity really the reason? I thought it was convergence of the integrand which allows the limit to be brought inside...

Comment: Not sure it is that fast. If you consider something like $t\mapsto \int \limits_{1385}^tf(nx)dx$, you want the limit in $n$ and not in $t$.

Comment: You can't reacht uniform convergence, but for fixed $t$, it will work.

Comment: Dominated convergence, assuming $f\in L^\infty$?

Comment: @AlexR But then you're talking about the function $n\to \int \limits _{1385}^{2006}f(nx)dx$ which isn't classically known to be continuous (taking $n$ over the positive reals). But maybe it is known, I don't know.

Comment: @GitGud You'll need some sort of monotone convergence for $f$, I added this to the answer. I left it out in the first place considering the undergraduate tag.

Comment: @BertrandR Maybe fix your MathJax before it's too late? ;-)

Comment: PS the integrand is not monotone necessarily

Comment: You really don't need to use any convergence theorems here...

Comment: Implicitly, you do. But as $1385$ is not on the edge of the domain, you can get $f(n\cdot) \in L^\infty ([1385, 2006])$ for free.

Comment: Yes, so for sufficiently large $n$ $|f(nx)| \leq 2$ for all $x \in [1385,2006]$. Dominated (or bounded?) convergence theorem works fine, but not monotone.

Comment: Let me say what I wanted to say in another (hopefully clearer) way : 
1. To get $\lim \int f_n(x)dx=\int \lim f_n(x) dx$, you need to prove it either by hand or with a theorem. Monotone and dominated convergence are far from being simple theorems, and taken as it is now, your answer is not accurate (and monotone doesn't work here, or at least not in the way I understood what you wrote).
2. Anyway, in this particular case, dominated and monotone convergence are really an overkill.

Comment: @AlexR: You don't need any convergence theorem. You only need to know that integration preserves order, that is, if $f\le g$ then $\int f \le \int g$.

Comment: This hint is misleading (and probably wrong but this is hard to tell since the phrasing is ambiguous). @upvoters Why the upvote?