# Two different calculations of a limit, one of them maybe wrong.

Tags: limits, proof-verification, proof-explanation

This is the limit:

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{ \displaystyle\int^{\pi+he^{-\frac{1}{h}}}_{0}x^2e^{-x^2}dx-\int^{\pi}_{0}x^2e^{-x^2}dx}{he^{-\frac{1}{h}}}$$

In the site I've seen it proposed to calculate, two solutions have been shown, one of them (the more straightforward one) dismissed as incorrect and the other one accepted. I see more dubious the accepted proof, and this makes more ashtonishing for me the rejecting of the other.

I write the calculations proposed for you to judge. And my questions are: is the dismissal correct? and, if affirmative, why?

**1.-**

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\int^{\pi+he^{-\frac{1}{h}}}_{0}x^2e^{-x^2}dx-\int^{\pi}_{0}x^2e^{-x^2}dx}{he^{-\frac{1}{h}}}  = \displaystyle  \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\int^{\pi+he^{-\frac{1}{h}}}_{\pi}x^2e^{-x^2}dx }{he^{-\frac{1}{h}}}$$

Making $x = \pi+h\,e^{-\frac{1}{h}}\,t \;\;\longrightarrow\;\;\text{dx} = h\,e^{-\frac{1}{h}}\,\text{dt}$

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\int^{\pi+he^{-\frac{1}{h}}}_{\pi}x^2e^{-x^2}dx }{he^{-\frac{1}{h}}} =\lim_{h\to 0}\int_{0}^{1} \left( \pi + he^{-\frac{1}{h} \, t}\right)^2 e^{-\left( \pi + he^{-\frac{1}{h} \, t}\right)^2} \text{dt}=$$

$$=\int_{0}^{1} \lim_{h\to 0}\left( \pi + he^{-\frac{1}{h} \, t}\right)^2 e^{-\left( \pi + he^{-\frac{1}{h} \, t}\right)^2}\text{dt} = \pi^2 e^{-\pi^2}$$

**2.-**

Let be $F(t)=\int_{0}^{t}x^2e^{-x^2}dx$, then $F'(t)=t^2e^{-t^2}$

Let be $\Delta t=+he^{-\frac{1}{h}}$, then $h\rightarrow{0}\Rightarrow{}\Delta t\rightarrow{0}$

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\int^{\pi+he^{-\frac{1}{h}}}_{0}x^2e^{-x^2}dx-\int^{\pi}_{0}x^2e^{-x^2}dx}{he^{-\frac{1}{h}}}=\lim_{\Delta t\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\int^{\pi+\Delta t}_{0}x^2e^{-x^2}dx-\int^{\pi}_{0}x^2e^{-x^2}dx}{\Delta t} =\lim_{\Delta t \to 0}{}\frac{F(\pi+\Delta t)-F(\pi)}{\Delta t}=F'(\pi)=\pi^2e^{-\pi^2}$$

Comment: just to clarify, which one is the "incorrect" one?

Comment: :) Well, I've left this point open. But if you are uncomfortable I can tell you wich one. I don't pretend make a riddle.

Comment: Note that $h\to 0$ and $\Delta t\to 0$ are NOT equivalent. You must require $h>0$ for this to be the case (i.e., you are only considering $h\searrow 0$).

Comment: @MPW Yes, I considered this point, but, hasn't the other proof the same problem? Aren't them both restricted to $ h>0$? And why is possible that "integral sign jump"?

Comment: The first proof passes the limit under the integral sign. This isn't always allowed and needs justification.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253696/can-a-limit-of-an-integral-be-moved-inside-the-integral

Comment: Obviously the second method is simpler and better and preferred. The first one unnecessarily complicates the problem by relying on interchange of limit operation with the integral sign.