# Move limit inside integral.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, integration, limits

$G(t)$ is a decreasing function and $0\leq G(t) \leq 1$, for all $t \in [0, \infty).$ I have calculate $$\lim_{\theta\to \infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}[G(t)]^\theta \,dt. $$ The answer to the question involve evaluating the integral and then taking the limit to prove the result; but I was wondering if it would be valid to move the integral inside the limit, that is
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\lim_{\theta\to \infty}[G(t)]^\theta \,dt=0.$$
Can you help me?

Comment: Relelvant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253696/can-a-limit-of-an-integral-be-moved-inside-the-integral

Comment: I remember there are some regularity conditions to do so. So in general, the answer is negative. You may add some more conditions on the function.

Comment: Is $G$ strictly decreasing? Or strictly less than $1$? Otherwise, $G(t) = 1$ would be a counterexample.

Comment: G is  strictly decreasing. Is it true?

Comment: If you assume also that the integral is convergent for $\theta = 1$, then yes, the result is true. I do have a way of proving it, but I fear it's a little inelegant. I'd be willing to write up an answer if you want to see it, but I think it'd be better if someone else wrote out a proof.

Comment: G is survival function for non-negative continuous random variable