# A question on finding partial derivative of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^{1}$ map. Define $u:(0, \infty)\times \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$ as

$$u(r,x)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int _{y\in S^{1}} f(x+ry)dy$$.

Then find $\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}$.

My attempt: $\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(r,x)= lim_{h\to 0} \frac{u(r+h,x)-u(r,x)}{h}$. This gives :

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(r,x)= lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{y\in S^{1}} \frac{(f(x+(r+h)y)-f(x+ry) ) }{h}$. Now taking limit inside we have

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(r,x)= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{y\in S^{1}} D_{y}f(x+ry)dy$, where $D_{y}f(x+ry)$ denotes the directional derivative of $f$ at $(x+ry)$, in the direction of $y$.

Is this a correct and complete answer or can I do something more? Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: How do you define integration on $S^1$?

Comment: It seems to me that it is line integral.

Comment: If you write down an explicit formula then things will be easier...

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply some result on the commutativity of derivation (or limit) with definite integration, e.g., this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

If you are familiar with the Lebesgue Integral, you find more here: [Can a limit of an integral be moved inside the integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253696/can-a-limit-of-an-integral-be-moved-inside-the-integral)