# Putting limit inside an integral to calculate $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals

I'm trying to prove: $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

I have defined $\; I(a)= \int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}e^{-ax}dx\;$ for $a>0$, and I'm trying to show that: $$\frac{dI}{da}(a)=-\int_0^\infty \sin(x)  e^{-ax}dx$$

I started like this: $$\frac{dI}{da}(a)= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{I(a+h)-I(a)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}\biggl(\frac{e^{-(a+h)x}-e^{-ax}}{h}\biggr)dx$$

Next I would like to put the limit inside the integral, and then I get what I want, but how can I justify this? Thanks

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253696/can-a-limit-of-an-integral-be-moved-inside-the-integral) might help.

Comment: have you tried the Leibniz integral rule, to derivate under the integral sign ?

Comment: I haven't learned the Leibniz integral rule. The only case I know I am allowed to put limits inside an integral is when I have uniform convergence, which in this case I'm not sure how to prove

Comment: One thing that you can do is just to copy the proof of the Leibniz rule for this specific case. The proof I know uses the DCT.

Comment: Your caution deserves praise, especially since even after showing $\displaystyle I(a)=\arctan\frac1a$, you'll still have to justify $\displaystyle\lim_{a\to0+}\int^\infty_0\frac{\sin x}x\,e^{-ax}\,dx=\int^\infty_0\frac{\sin x}x\,\lim_{a\to0+}e^{-ax}\,dx$.

Comment: Is there a way to justify putting the limit inside the integeral with Fubini's theorem?

Comment: @user401516 that might be an option!!

Comment: @Shashi can you point me on how to do it? I'v tried for a while and couldn't find a way.

Comment: @user401516 I think some use it to find the Dirichlet integral, just searching a bit in MSE will give results. Tell me your opinion on the things that you will find!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Fubini to calculate $I(a)$:
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 e^{-ax}\frac{\sin x}x\,dx&=\int^\infty_0 e^{-ax}\int^1_0\cos tx\,dt\,dx
\\&=\int^1_0\int^\infty_0 e^{-ax}\cos tx\,dx\,dt
\\&=\int^1_0\frac{a}{a^2+t^2}\,dt=\arctan\frac1a
\end{align}
Since $|\cos tx|\le1$, the double integral is absolutely convergent for any $a>0$.
As I said, this is not enough, we have to justify $\displaystyle I(0)=\lim_{a\to0+}I(a)$. We have 
$$I(0)-I(a)=\int^\infty_0\sin x\,\frac{1-e^{-ax}}x\,dx=\int^\infty_0\cos x\,\frac{1-(1+ax)\,e^{-ax}}{x^2}\,dx$$ by partial integration. Now, we can use the dominated convergence theorem, because $|\cos x|\le1$, and the fraction is $\ge0$ and $\le$ the minimum of $a^2$ and $x^{-2}$, i.e. dominated by an integrable function on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: How can I use it to push to limit inside the integral?

Comment: @user401516 I've just added the necessary details.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is possible only if the function is itegrable. Then because of linearity of derivation, integral and limit you can substitute them. This is possible since ${sinx\over x}{e^-ax}$ is integrable and bounded for $x\in [0,\infty)$ when $a\ge0$

Comment: When $a=0$, this function is not absolutely integrable over $[0,\infty)$

Comment: It doesn't require for absolute integrability. It suffices only to be integrable....

Comment: In the sense of an Improper Riemann integrable? Do you have a reference for your claim? Now I am curious.

Comment: Sure! Please refer two "Real Mathematical Analysis" written by Charles C. Pugh