# How to argue that $\lim_{a\to \infty} \int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\frac {\cos{ay}}{y}\, dy$ is $0$.

Tags: integration, limits

Suppose $\alpha, \beta>0$, I want to compute
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac {\cos(\alpha x)-\cos(\beta x)}{x}\, dx.
\end{align*}
I've change it to the following
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\sin (xy)\, dy\, dx.
\end{align*}
and get:
\begin{align*}
\ln{\frac {\beta}{\alpha}}-\lim_{a\to \infty}  \int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\frac {\cos{ay}}{y}\, dy.
\end{align*}

The final answer is $\ln{\frac {\beta}{\alpha}}$. I wonder how to argue the limit part is $0$. Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Residue Theorem?

Comment: This is riemann lebesgue lemma for the integrable function $\frac{1}{y}$

Comment: Integration by parts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgive me for my previous somewhat vague answer.

This is not so much an answer but rather a suggestion for a path to the answer,

First off, I believe there are places where we have to be a bit careful. I will mark them with an $(\ast)$ below:

\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty\int_\alpha^\beta \sin(xy) dydx &= \int_\alpha^\beta\int_0^\infty \tag{$\ast_1$} \sin(xy)dxdy \\
&=\int_\alpha^\beta \frac{-\cos(xy)}{y} \Bigr\rvert_0^\infty dy \\
&=-\int_\alpha^\beta \lim_{a\to \infty}\left(\frac{\cos(ay)}{y}\right) - \lim_{a\to 0}\left(\frac{\cos(ay)}{y}\right) dy \\
&= \int_\alpha^\beta \lim_{a\to 0}\left(\frac{\cos(ay)}{y}\right) dy - 
\int_\alpha^\beta \lim_{a\to \infty}\left(\frac{\cos(ay)}{y}\right) dy \\
&= \int_\alpha^\beta \frac{1}{y}dy - \int_\alpha^\beta \lim_{a\to \infty}\left(\frac{\cos(ay)}{y}\right) dy \\
&= \ln(\beta/\alpha) - \int_\alpha^\beta \lim_{a\to \infty}\left(\frac{\cos(ay)}{y}\right) dy \\
&= \ln(\beta/\alpha) - \lim_{a\to \infty}\int_\alpha^\beta \left(\frac{\cos(ay)}{y}\right) dy \tag{$\ast_2$} \\
&= \ln(\beta/\alpha)
\end{align*}

Now, before I address the two asteriks I will explain how we got from the second to last line to the last line. Inspired by Conrad's comment, The Riemman-Lebesgue Lemma states the following (I am citing this link (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Riemann-LebesgueLemma.html) as my source for the statement of this lemma)

If $f(x)$ is integrable on $[-\pi, \pi]$, then 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin(tx)dx = 0
\end{equation*}
In our case $f(x) = 1/y$. However I am unsure if we can generalize this lemma to any interval $[\alpha,\beta]$.

Now, as for the asteriks, for the first one it is not trivial that we can apply Fubini's theorem here and I THINK that we have to apply some measure theory to make this change of order of integration a little bit more rigorous. The same goes for the second asteriks. It is not trivial that we can move the limit outside of the integral and I think we have to apply another result from measure theory to make this second asteriks more rigorous. This thread ([Can a limit of an integral be moved inside the integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253696/can-a-limit-of-an-integral-be-moved-inside-the-integral)) discusses which results might be useful.

Comment: Hi, can you please expand on your answer by completing it with details? It's quite hard to get what exactly your proof is, this seems to be way too brief of an outline.

Comment: Sorry yes you're right my answer was very vague. I just edited it. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great and well-written answer. :)

Comment: No thank you lol had you not said something I would have never figured out what I now know about measure theory and the subtleties of Fubinis theorem

Comment: For Riemann Lebesgue lemma, you can have any interval like $[a, b] $. The proof works by first establishing the lemma for step functions and then using the fact that the function can be approximated well enough via step functions