# Finding Improper Integral $\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_0^a\frac{\tan^{-1}x\tan^{-1}(a-x)}{a}\,\mathrm{d}x$.

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have used `sympy` to evaluate this for large $a$ and I think that this converges to a value of $\frac{\pi^2}{4}$ but I am not able to arrive at this analytically. So I guess I want to prove analytically: $$ \lim_{a\to\infty}\int_0^a\frac{\tan^{-1}x\tan^{-1}(a-x)}{a}\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi^2}{4}$$

I have tried Integrating by parts, and Feynman's integral trick but I arrive at integrals which I don't know how to deal.

Comment: Put $x=at$, then the integral becomes $$
\int_0^1 {\arctan (at)\arctan (a(1 - t))dt} .
$$ Now use dominated convergence.

Comment: @Gary Thank you for helping. From https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253696/can-a-limit-of-an-integral-be-moved-inside-the-integral#253697, I understand that dominated convergence theorem helps to take the limit operation inside the integral. The results follows. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you can dominate the integrand on $(0,1)$ by $\frac{\pi}{2} \times \frac{\pi}{2}$, which is integrable on $(0,1)$. Hence you can move the limit operator inside the integral. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem