# Limit with an improper integral

Tags: limits, improper-integrals, indeterminate-forms

Is it true that

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}x\int_{0}^\infty k^5 dk=0$$

Seems like this has an indeterminate form, but I am being told it equals zero.

Comment: $\int^\infty_0 k^5~\mathrm{d}k$ is usually not defined.

Comment: It would be useful to know who told you that and what *their* arguments are.  $\int_0^\infty k^5dk$ is infinite, so you cannot even multiply it by $x$, let alone take the limit! So for me it is almost "case closed" but I would like to give the person who told you it was zero the benefit of the doubt. (Or, more likely, correct *their* misunderstanding.)

Comment: @StinkingBishop It was a tutor. Their argument was along the lines that the integral can be represented as a series, and since each individual term in the series multiplied by x goes to zero, the whole integral does as well.

Comment: It *is* true that in some cases you can swap limit and integral. If the argument is $\lim_{x\to 0}x\int_0^\infty k^5dk=\lim_{x\to 0}\int_0^\infty xk^5dk\overset{???}{=}\int_0^\infty (\lim_{x\to 0}xk^5)dk=\int_0^\infty 0\cdot dk=0$,  then the problem is to justify the step $\overset{???}{=}$. In this case it is not justified. Have a look at e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/253697/700480 for some criteria.

Comment: (And, in fact here you have two limits: $\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_0^a xk^5dk$ and the "outer" limit needs to "skip over" both the inner limit and the (proper) integral. $\int_0^a$.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this clears up some confusion on my end!

Comment: A simpler example where you have a sequence of series. They are all convergent, sum of each is $1$ but each individual term converges ultimately to $0$.  Look at this: $1+0+0+0+\ldots, 0+1+0+0+\ldots, 0+0+1+0+\ldots, \ldots$, so the hand-wavy argument that if individual terms tend to $0$ the whole sum needs to tend to   zero just doesn't work. Again, there *are* cases when it does (e.g. when the convergence is *uniform*) but the onus would be on your tutor to recall and use the relevant theorems in the proof (if any).